# how to display a new tableview from user selecting a row in tableview on same view in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a table view which contains multiple rows data from service,i want to display a new tableview(t2) with sliding animation over a tableview(t1) when selecting a row of tableview(t1). the tableview(t2) can contain some data from server pass by selecting row value.

Comment: what is your question ? Presenting a tableview ? sliding from top or from bottom ? Where is the code ?

Comment: http://www.innofied.com/accordion-view-ios/

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/skstableview   try these

Comment: accordion is an expandable table @abhi1992!!! OP wants to present a new tableview on a tableview!!!!!

Comment: You want table2 to subview on table1 ?

Answer (score -1):

Adding TableView inside Other Table view in not possible. Another way to do this is you can use Master-Detail UI.